# Can I return a selected reference in c++?

Tags: c++

Please see following sudo code.

```
Object& getObjectDependingOnMonth(std::string& month, std::vector<Object>& vec) {

    if (month == "January") {
        auto& ref = vec.at(1);
    } else {
        auto& ref = vec.at(2);
    }

    ref.do_something();  // error because ref is local in block above.

    return ref;  // error because ref is local in block above.
}
```

The above code shows what I want to do. I would like to get a reference of element of a vector. It depends on an input, month. I would like to use its reference outside the function, getObjectDependingOnMonth(...). However I could not think of how to return valid reference of a selected element in vector without duplicated code in blocks. auto& ref = ... is defined in a if block. The ref are invalid outside its block.

Could I return a selected reference from a function?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Does this compile as `ref` goes out of scope

Comment: @BeyelerStudios : I am sorry for my mistake. I change std::vector<Object> -> std::vector<Object>& not to use temporal vector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change the code:

```
if (month == "January") {
    auto& ref = vec.at(1);
} else {
    auto& ref = vec.at(2);
}
```

to the following so that you have one reference

```
auto& ref = vec.at(month == "January" ? 1 : 2);
```

Comment: thank you for telling me a solution. Thanks to your solution, I learn it is important to divide selection of element and assignment to reference. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ it's very idiomatic to use iterators indicating a position in a container:

```
auto getObjectDependingOnMonth(const std::string& month, std::vector<Object>& vec) {
    decltype(vec.begin()) pos;

    if (month == "January")
        pos = vec.size() > 1 ? vec.begin() + 1 : vec.end();
    else
        pos = vec.size() > 2 ? vec.begin() + 2 : vec.end();

    if(pos != vec.end())
        pos->do_something();

    return pos;
}
```

Comment: what about, `auto pos = std::begin(vet);` and then `pos = std::advance(pos, i);` no need for decltype or the condition operator

Comment: @BeyelerStudios : thank you for telling me another solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes!!

```
Object& getObjectDependingOnMonth(std::string& month, std::vector<Object>& vec) {

    if (month == "January") {
        vec.at(1).do_something();
        return vec.at(1);
    } else {
        vec.at(2).do_something();
        return vec.at(2);
    }
```

}

Comment: thank you for telling me answer. Please let me ask you more. My code has much code after vec.at(). Your solution needs much duplicated code in each block. Can I avoid it?

Comment: Maybe I should put all code in do_something() to avoid duplicated code. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps read [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)